# Inconsistent results when dealing with endianness and arrays in C++

Tags: c++, endianness

I'm wondering why — in my sample code — when converting a reference to the first element of `m_arr` to a pointer of bigger size the program reads the memory to `m_val` in little-endian byte order? With this way of thinking `*(std::uint8_t*)m_arr` should point to 0x38, but it doesn't.

My CPU uses little-endian byte order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::uint8_t m_arr[2] = { 0x5a, 0x38 };

    // explain why m_val is 0x385a and not 0x5a38
    std::uint16_t m_val = *(std::uint16_t*)m_arr;

    std::cout << std::hex << m_val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: That said, this looks perfectly WAI. The little end (the least significant one) is the first array element. The value is `a[0] + 0x100 * a[1]`. That's what "little-endian" means.

Comment: That's expected behaviour for a little endian system isn't it? the least significant byte (0x5a) is in the lower address

Comment: This code violates the struct aliasing rule (lvalue of type `uint16_t` is used to access something different)

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood what little-endian means

Comment: `*(std::uint8_t*)m_arr` should not point to 0x38. You're taking an array of `std::uint8_t`, and performing an explicit array-to-pointer conversion. This gives you back a pointer to the first element. Endianness is irrelevant there because the pointee type is the same type as the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte ordering is the order in which bytes are laid out when referenced as their native type. Regardless of whether your machine is big or little endian, a sequence of bytes is always in its natural order.

The situation you describe (where the first byte is `0x38`) is what you would observe if you created a `uint16_t` and got a `uint8_t` pointer to it. Instead, you have a `uint8_t` array and you get a `uint16_t` pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Little endian means that the **least significant** byte goes first: [image]

So translate that logic to your array, `{ 0x5a, 0x38 }`. On a little endian system, the `0x5a` is least significant and `0x38` is most significant... hence you get `0x385a`.